# Promote our site and earn a Booster badge or a Publicist badge!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, badges

Stack Exchange awards badges to people who promote our site.

- The [**Announcer** badge](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer) is awarded to anyone who shares a **link to a question that is later visited by 25 unique IP addresses**.
- The [**Booster** badge](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/booster) is awarded to anyone who shares a **link to a question later visited by 300 unique IP addresses**.
- The [**Publicist** badge](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist) is awarded to anyone who shares a **link to a question later visited by 1000 unique IP addresses**.

Each of these badges can be awarded multiple times. At the time of writing (20 December 2020), the Announced badge has been awarded 25 times, but only two persons on our site have been awarded a Booster badge.

I will create two answers to this question:

- one with a lists of the first ten people on our site who get an Booster badge, and
- one with a list of the first ten who get a Publicist badge.

**How do you share a link to get one of the site promotion badge?**

The link should be created be clicking on the `share` link below a question or an answer. This will generate a link that contains your user ID, so the system can track who shared the link. For example, if I click on the `share` link below this question, I get the following URL: `https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1505/2191`. The number `1505` represents the question; the number `2191` represents my user ID on Literature Stack Exchange. You can share this kind of link on social media or on other sites that get a lot of traffic.

(This question was inspired by [Expatriates SE](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/q/333/10067).)

Answer (score 2):

### First Ten to a Get a Booster Badge

1. [Kate Gregory](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/417/kate-gregory) (12 March 2017: [How do we know Humpty Dumpty was an egg?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/how-do-we-know-humpty-dumpty-was-an-egg))
2. [Mithical](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/58/mithical) (5 April 2017: [What is Hobbes?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/621/what-is-hobbes))
3. [Adam Lear♦](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/1/adam-lear) (9 November 2021: [Why does "less than" mean "not" in "A little more than kin, and less than kind"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19943/))
4. ?
5. ?
6. ?
7. ?
8. ?
9. ?
10. ?

Answer (score 2):

### First Ten to a Get a Publicist Badge

1. [Kate Gregory](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/417/kate-gregory) (12 March 2017: [How do we know Humpty Dumpty was an egg?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/how-do-we-know-humpty-dumpty-was-an-egg))
2. [Mithical](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/58/mithical) (29 July 2018: [What is Hobbes?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/621/what-is-hobbes))
3. ?
4. ?
5. ?
6. ?
7. ?
8. ?
9. ?
10. ?